# Erro ao abrir e fechar modais

Tags: javascript, html, css

Javascript

```
var inicio = document.getElementById('inicio-modal');
var banner = document.getElementById('banner-modal');
var produto = document.getElementById('produtos-modal');

function abreInicio(){
    if (inicio.style.display == 'none') {
        inicio.style.display = 'block';
        banner.style.display = 'none';
        produto.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function abreBanners(){
    if (banner.style.display == 'none') {
        banner.style.display = 'block';
        inicio.style.display = 'none';
        produto.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function abreProdutos(){
    if (produto.style.display == 'none') {
        produto.style.display = 'block';
        inicio.style.display = 'none';
        banner.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="inicio-modal" class="modal"></div>
<div id="banner-modal" class="modal" style='display:none;'></div>
<div id="produtos-modal" class="modal" style='display:none;'></div>
```

CSS

```
.modal{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
}
```

Quando a página é carregada e o primeiro modal está aberto, tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém, ao clicar nos botões para abrir e fechar os modais, eles perdem suas margens do css.

Comment: No seu código, ao abrir um modal, você o atribui um `display: inline-block`. Ele está assim por padrão?

Comment: Era esse mesmo o erro, obrigado :D

Comment: Murilo, não adicione "Corrigido" ao título, você pode (deve :P) responder sua própria pergunta e favoritá-la, assim terá o mesmo intuito e será melhor para novas visitas entenderem como o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi utilizado o display: `inline-block`, que na verdade tinha como padrão `block`, por isso o erro acontecia, ao corrigir para seu padrão (`block`), tudo voltou a funcionar normalmente